# pydub не может преобразовать mp3 в wav

Tags: python, аудио, ffmpeg

Код:
    import pydub
    sound = pydub.AudioSegment.from_mp3("D:/mp3/n.mp3")
    sound.export("D:/mp3/c.wav", format="wav")

> Warning (from warnings module):   File
>   "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\pydub\utils.py",
>   line 165
>       warn("Couldn't find ffmpeg or avconv - defaulting to ffmpeg, but may not work", RuntimeWarning) RuntimeWarning: Couldn't find ffmpeg or
>   avconv - defaulting to ffmpeg, but may not work
>
> Warning (from warnings module):   File
>   "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\pydub\utils.py",
>   line 193
>       warn("Couldn't find ffprobe or avprobe - defaulting to ffprobe, but may not work", RuntimeWarning) RuntimeWarning: Couldn't find
>   ffprobe or avprobe - defaulting to ffprobe, but may not work Traceback
>   (most recent call last):   File "D:\mp3\1.py", line 2, in 
>       sound = pydub.AudioSegment.from_mp3("D:/mp3/n.mp3")   File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\pydub\audio_segment.py",
>   line 716, in from_mp3
>       return cls.from_file(file, 'mp3', parameters=parameters)   File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\pydub\audio_segment.py",
>   line 665, in from_file
>       info = mediainfo_json(orig_file)   File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\pydub\utils.py",
>   line 263, in mediainfo_json
>       res = Popen(command, stdin=stdin_parameter, stdout=PIPE, stderr=PIPE)   File
>   "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\subprocess.py",
>   line 854, in **init**
>       self._execute_child(args, executable, preexec_fn, close_fds,   File
>   "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\subprocess.py",
>   line 1307, in _execute_child
>       hp, ht, pid, tid = _winapi.CreateProcess(executable, args, FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2] Не удается найти указанный файл
>   Я устанавливал ffmpeg с помощью pip, но всё равно присутствует эта ошибка.

Comment: установи ffmpeg там где pydub его ищет или скажи ему где искать

Comment: каким образом мне это сделать?

Comment: смотрю я тут исходники, мне кажется ничего не выйдет под виндовс.

Comment: попробуй конечно добавить в PATH папку где лежит ffmpeg.exe